# useGlobalPipes and useStaticAssets in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nest

When I create an application using nestjs I have come across some weird problem.

When I create an application without type `useStaticAssets` method is not working:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(process.cwd(), 'uploads')); --> Property 'useStaticAssets' does not exist on type 'INestApplication'
```

But when I use type annotation `useStaticAssets` is working but `useGlobalPipes` method is not working:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(.         // --> Property 'useGlobalPipes' does not exist on type 'NestExpressApplication'
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(process.cwd(), 'uploads'));
```

I dont know what to do?

When I use whether type, both methods should work

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
```

You might be importing from the wrong path. It is working fine. `NestExpressApplication` extends `INestApplication`.

```
export interface NestExpressApplication<
  TServer extends CoreHttpServer | CoreHttpsServer = CoreHttpServer,
> extends INestApplication<TServer> {
```